# Drupal token for current page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Hello I hope I explain this correctly.

I am trying to populated the current page title in a webform default value field.

I can return node id or name using %nid - The node ID. %title - The node title.

Anyone any idea what I need to key in to populate the current page title??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is a replacement token for the html title. But it usually generated by a pattern; `[site-name] | [page-title]`. Can't you replicate the pattern?

Comment: if i key [page-title] it just displays as this and not actual page title.

Comment: I meant node-title, the one you access by %title, you might have to look up module specific replacement patterns

Comment: %title give node title not page title.  thanks anyway

Comment: But in most cases page title is defined by a pattern that includes also the node title (like my first example) can't you use a similar pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Drupal-style tokens if you upgrade to [Webform 4](http://drupal.org/project/webform), allowing you to set `[current-page:title]` as a component value.